# appium selenium cant send phone number keys

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

[image]

Hi,Normally I can use  the sendkey method but for the MobilePhone element I cant this,.I tried to send key one by one ,part part,or text etc.it didnt work.Could you pls help me?
My codes:

```
List<WebElement> menu22 =driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText")); 
 menu22.get(3).click();
         ((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_6);
         ((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_5);
         ((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_7);
         ((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_6);
         ((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_6);
         ((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_5);
         ((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_7);
         ((AndroidDriver) driver).pressKeyCode(AndroidKeyCode.KEYCODE_6);
The other my codes:


List<String> tel = Arrays.asList("5", "4", "5", "8", "5","3", "4", "5", "8", "5");
         for (int i = 0; i < tel.size(); i++) {
             menu22.get(3).sendKeys(tel.get(tel.size()-1-i));
             driver.hideKeyboard();
        }
```

and the other codes:

```
 menu22.get(3).sendKeys("5458650215"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use the following capabilities

capabilities.setCapability("unicodeKeyboard", true);
capabilities.setCapability("resetKeyboard", true);

This should helps in hide keyboard, that is, during test execution keyboard doesn't appear at all, soft keys will execute on behalf

Comment: If that doesn't work then try the following settings in device manually, 

go to device settings -> Language & Input and change default keyboard to Appium Android Input Manager for Unicode and now tap on any EditText field, 

see if the keyboard is not popping up, if so
then run the test again

Answer (score 0):

This happens for some elements in the mobile app. To type in such elements using driver keyboard as below:

```
List<WebElement> menu22 =driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.EditText")); 


menu22.get(3).click();

driver.getKeyboard().sendKeys("Your Text to be typed");
```